# jenkins pipeline giving inexplicable NullPointerException at GenericDownloadExecutor.java: 52

Tags: jenkins, nullpointerexception, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

I followed the example given in this page to download artifacts from JFrog artifactory:
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Scripted+Pipeline+Syntax#ScriptedPipelineSyntax-UploadingandDownloadingFiles

But I have been getting NullPointerException. Below is the script output and error:

```
[Pipeline] echo
download spec {
    "files": [
        {
            "pattern": "aod-libs-release/path-to-artifact/deployment/DM-DP-V3A.24-RELEASE/deployment-DM-DP-V3A.24-RELEASE.zip",
            "target": "./artifacts"
        }, {
            "pattern": "aod-libs-release/path-to-artifact/dm-auth-web-services/DM-AU-V3A.88-RELEASE/dm-auth-web-services-DM-AU-V3A.88-RELEASE.war",
            "target": "./artifacts"
        }
    ]
}
[Pipeline] echo
artifactory server org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.common.types.ArtifactoryServer@66026154
[Pipeline] newBuildInfo
[Pipeline] artifactoryDownload
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.common.executors.GenericDownloadExecutor.execute(GenericDownloadExecutor.java:52)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.scripted.steps.DownloadStep$Execution.runStep(DownloadStep.java:67)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.scripted.steps.DownloadStep$Execution.runStep(DownloadStep.java:53)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.ArtifactorySynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.run(ArtifactorySynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:54)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Below is my jenkins pipeline script

```
def artifactoryServer = Artifactory.server("Artifactory-instance-id")
artifactoryServer.connection.timeout = 300
def artifactDownloadSpec = """{
    "files": [
        {
            "pattern": "aod-libs-release/path-to-artifact/deployment/${env.DP_VERSION}/deployment-${env.DP_VERSION}.zip",
            "target": "./artifacts"
        }, {
            "pattern": "aod-libs-release/path-to-artifact/dm-auth-web-services/${env.VERSION}/dm-auth-web-services-${env.VERSION}.war",
            "target": "./artifacts"
        }
    ]
}"""

echo "download spec " + artifactDownloadSpec
echo "artifactory server " + artifactoryServer
artifactoryServer.download spec: artifactDownloadSpec
```

I googled for GenericDownloadExecutor.java and found below code, but cannot figure out what I am missing that line 52 needed. Looks like a field is not set.

https://github.com/jenkinsci/artifactory-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jfrog/hudson/pipeline/common/executors/GenericDownloadExecutor.java

Comment: What is your Jenkins Artifactory plugin version?

Comment: @yahavi. Artifactory Plugin  3.13.1  I just upgraded to this version, because an earlier version was giving the exact same error.

Comment: I manage to reproduce the issue when I used `agent none`. Is it your case?

Comment: Not sure. Certainly, I did not configure any agent. Please point to where I can configure agent. Thanks

Comment: @yahavi. ok got it. I needed to put it inside a pipeline stage. It got past that error. Thanks for you help.

Comment: I wrote a detailed answer to help others who find this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running `artifactoryServer.download` step requires using an agent.
For example:

**Jenkins scripted pipeline**

```
node {
  ...
  artifactoryServer.download spec: artifactDownloadSpec
  ...
}
```

**Jenkins declarative pipeline**

The recommended way is to use the [rtDownload](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/declarative+Pipeline+Syntax#DeclarativePipelineSyntax-UploadingandDownloadingFiles) step, however, if you still want to use `artifactoryServer.download`:

```
pipeline {
    agent any // <- Make sure there is an active agent
    stages {
        stage('Example') {
            steps {
                script {
                  ...
                  artifactoryServer.download spec: artifactDownloadSpec
                  ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Read more:

1. [Uploading and Downloading Files](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/scripted+Pipeline+Syntax#ScriptedPipelineSyntax-UploadingandDownloadingFiles)
2. [Scripted pipeline example](https://github.com/jfrog/project-examples/blob/master/jenkins-examples/pipeline-examples/scripted-examples/exclude-patterns-download-example/Jenkinsfile)
3. [Declarative pipeline example](https://github.com/jfrog/project-examples/blob/master/jenkins-examples/pipeline-examples/declarative-examples/exclude-patterns-download-example/Jenkinsfile)
4. [Scripted pipeline inside declarative pipeline example](https://github.com/jfrog/project-examples/blob/master/jenkins-examples/pipeline-examples/scripted-examples/declarative-example/Jenkinsfile) - Less recommended, but this example is like your case